# Passing in variable name instead of the actual value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the below query that extracts data from JSON field in Redshift DB. I am however trying to see if I can have a variable passed instead of the actual argument in the below query. I mean, I would like to have person1 stored in a variable and pass it that variable name instead of the actual name. Reason I am trying to do is to have this same query used dynamically for different values.

```
select json_extract_path(jsonb_extract_array_element_text(column_name)::json,
'person1', 'name') from table
```

**Variable name**

`person` = `person1`

I would like to use the variable `person` in the above query instead of `person1` as used above. I tried to pass in that value but it returned `None` This would help me re-use this when the value changes from `person1` to `person2` and so on

Answer (score 1):

There is no "variable substitution" within Amazon Redshift.

You would need to do this in your program / SQL Client before sending the SQL query to Amazon Redshift. Such capabilities are common in SQL client tools and libraries.